# Scaling an image from pixels to inches

Tags: math, pixel, scaling

My maths just doesn't seem to be adding up. I've created an image where 30 pixels represents 1 inch. When I save the image, I want it to be scaled by a certain amount so that the pixels are converted to the correct inches.

What do I scale by??!!!

I'm currently scaling by 3.2 but I'm not sure if that's correct because the measurements seem off.

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking for, but I assume you are looking for a tool that maps pixels to inches on the screen. This varies by screen resolution and size, if you calculate the DPI (https://www.sven.de/dpi/ shown as PPI) of the monitor you want to show it on you can use this to get the desired conv: 
http://auctionrepair.com/pixels.html

Comment: It's difficult to explain. I have an image which has been drawn. So say that image is 3x3 pixels, I've multiplied it by 30 so that it can be seen on the screen. So now it's 90x90 pixels.
But on print I don't want to print out 90x90 pixels. I actually want to print out 3x3 inches (which corresponds to the 3x3 pixels). 
My logic is, assuming there are 96 pixels in an inch, I will multiply by 96 and divide by 30 (as I multiplied up by 30 before). This will then equate to a scaling 3.2. But I don't think that's working :(

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. There's no direct calculation. Thanks!